# Identity Server: Token Type jwt vs reference using Implicit Flow Authentication with OIDC

Tags: angular, jwt, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am following the example provided by damienbod [Ang2 Id Serv 4 OIDC](https://damienbod.com/2016/03/02/angular2-openid-connect-implicit-flow-with-identityserver4/), where I have the following : an identity Server (modified implementation), Resource API and ng-2 application.

After getting authenticated from the identity server and trying to access my protected API, it always give me error 401 (Unauthorized).

I have changed the Client on the identity Server to use Token Type of jwt instead of reference and then it worked.

**Client configuration on the identity server:**

```
                ClientName = "angular2client",
                ClientId = "angular2client",
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,               
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                //redirect urls are ommited
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                   "openid",
                   "resourceAPIs",
                    "role",
                }
```

**Resource API**: Identity Validation

```
 app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:44311",
            ScopeName = "resourceAPIs",

            RequireHttpsMetadata = false
        });
```

I need to know, why the jwt token type made it work and what code to modify to make the reference type token works?

Answer (score 3):

To use reference token you need to provide scope secret. See [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/endpoints/introspection.html)

> The introspection endpoint requires authentication using a scope
>   secret.

Identity Server:

```
            ClientName = "angular2client",
            ClientId = "angular2client",
            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,               
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            //redirect urls are ommited
            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
               "openid",
               "resourceAPIs",
                "role",
            }
```

Resource Server

```
    app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "http://localhost:44311",
        ScopeName = "resourceAPIs",
        ScopeSecret = "secret",
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false
    });
```